# What's the difference between the worst case and average case of a problem?

Tags: cryptography, complexity-theory, computation-theory

I'm studying the reduction about some hard problems on the lattice. What's the meaning of "worst case to average case reduction" ? For example, the paper "Worst-case to Average-case Reductions based on Gaussian Measures" gives the reduction from the worst case INCGDD problem to average case SIS problem, what does it mean?

Answer (score 1):

A problem has average-case time complexity *C* if there exists an algorithm that solves the problem in *C* time on average, if the inputs are chosen randomly according to some distribution. Formalizing this is tricky, see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Average-case_complexity).

A problem has a *worse case to average case reduction* if you can show the following: if an algorithm solving the problem with average-case complexity *C* exists then this algorithm can be applied to also solve the worst-case with the same complexity (modulo a polynomial factor).